# What is the meaning of case in match pattern in scala?

Tags: scala

```
  val list1 = List(1, 1, 2, 3, 5,7,8,4)
  def lastrecursive[A](ls :List[A]):A = ls match{
  case p :: Nil => p    // what is the meaning of Nil
  case _ :: tail => lastrecursive(tail)
  case _ => throw new NoSuchElementException
   }
```

For the code ABOVE in recursive format. Can anyone explain why we are giving 
    :: and case h and case tail and case _. while working on list match pattern.

```
   and for reversing a list
    def reverseRecursive[A](ls: List[A]): List[A] = ls match {
     case Nil       => Nil
     case h :: tail => reverseRecursive(tail) ::: List(h)
          }
```

how this ::: List(h) works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the :: method is used to construct and deconstruct a list. a::b means the head of the list is a (a single element) and the tail is b (a list).

p::Nil means a case where there is some element p and the tail is the empty list (Nil).

This case basically finds the last actual element in the list.

The second case is similar: h::tail  means an element h and a list tail. So we reverse the tail and then add the list of h to the end (l1 ::: l2 prepends the **list** l1 to the **list** l).

Comment: Well... I beleive it will be a better choice to use the word `method` instead of `operator` in this case. And `::` is not used for either of constructing or deconstructing a list. It is actally a `right associative` `method` which `prepends` an element to a `List`. When you see  `p :: Nil`, then `Nil` is the empty list to which `p` is `prepended` to.

Comment: `operator` is a very standard word with a very standard meaning. And it is not "name for a method with non alpha numeric name". I will suggest that you avoid using the word `operator` when talking about Scala.

Comment: Thanks for the Explanation.
Can anyone tell what is best resource or way to learn scala.
and code with more understanding rather than copying frfom google for  a beginner who starts learning scala

Comment: There are many. Twitter Scala School is one of them: https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/

Comment: a good Scala book is better than anything available free online: http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/books.html

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh We say operator all the time? http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#prefix-infix-and-postfix-operations http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/01-lexical-syntax.html#identifiers